# How to simplify this acronym generator?

Tags: python

I wrote code for an acronym generator. I can only get it to work for up to ten words.

I feel the code is unnecessarily repetitive. Is there a simpler way to do this? Can it work for a larger sets of words?

I just started coding and I have no prior knowledge of programming so I might need detailed explanation in your answers.

```
userInput = input('enter name of the organization not more than ten words: ')
listInput = userInput.split()


if len(listInput) == 1:
    a = listInput[0]
    acronym = a[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 2:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 3:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 4:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 5:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    e = listInput[4]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0] + e[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 6:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    e = listInput[4]
    f = listInput[5]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0] + e[0] + f[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 7:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    e = listInput[4]
    f = listInput[5]
    g = listInput[6]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0] + e[0] + f[0] + g[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 8:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    e = listInput[4]
    f = listInput[5]
    g = listInput[6]
    h = listInput[7]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0] + e[0] + f[0] + g[0] + h[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
elif len(listInput) == 9:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    e = listInput[4]
    f = listInput[5]
    g = listInput[6]
    h = listInput[7]
    i = listInput[8]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0] + e[0] + f[0] + g[0] + h[0] + i[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
else:
    a = listInput[0]
    b = listInput[1]
    c = listInput[2]
    d = listInput[3]
    e = listInput[4]
    f = listInput[5]
    g = listInput[6]
    h = listInput[7]
    i = listInput[8]
    j = listInput[9]
    acronym = a[0] + b[0] + c[0] + d[0] + e[0] + f[0] + g[0] + h[0] + i[0] + j[0]
    print(acronym.upper())
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a loop, a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) or a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) to handle dynamic length data:

```
userInput = input('enter name of the organization not more than ten words: ')
listInput = userInput.split()

acro = ''.join(token[0].upper() for token in listInput)
print(acro)
```

This uses [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a generator expression to combine the initials into a single string.